# Can anyone help fix this old black & white photo?

Tags: image-processing

I have this family photo that for as long as I can remember (40+ years) has white through the top half of the photo.  I would like to try to correct the photo or get someone to do it for me.  Any help would be appreciated.
 [image]

Comment: This site is really for learning about photography — it's not meant to be a service for finding someone to do work for you. You'll probably get better results asking for ways to fix a problem like this — and you might get some examples of efforts towards that goal. But if you are asking for someone to just do the restoration for you, there are forums (and for that matter, commercial services) that are a better fit.

Answer (score 1):

A professional retoucher/restorer might be able to do it.
I've got to admit it's probably beyond my abilities. The sky isn't too difficult to clean up, & getting rid of the small dings & scratches is time-consuming but not difficult [so I didn't do much of that except for the big one in the sky], but that stripe across the middle is tough.

Maybe if I gave it 2 or 3 hours rather than 5 or 10 minutes ;)

[image]

Quick A/B diagonal mask.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to take it to a professional retoucher or risk going through several students to achieve a finished product. They would likely use digital means, such as scanning the photo then using software like Photoshop to do the actual correction, because while physically retouching the photo is possible it's usually not preferred because of cost, time, and risk of not getting it just right.

After you've received the original photo back you'll want to place it in an archiving sleeve to maintain its integrity or if you're happy with the restored image have one of those archived and another out on display.

Google "photo restorationists" or "retouchers" to match to someone providing this service.

Comment: I provide such services for a cost. If it's something you want to pursue I'll pass over my contact information.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was left out bent or something. It's been exposed to uv and it has lost a lot of info - a lot of the black ink. The problem is that the main defect is a gradient.

I made a copy of the top half and used a gradient on the bottom so it blends. Then added contrast and darkened the top and removed a little contrast and lightened the bottom. Did a little overlay on the face and removed specks.

It's something somebody could work on and get the line of haze to disappear more but the overall image quality can't get that much better.

This photo would easily make a great painting or drawing. You know, have a real person draw it.

[image]